# How to optimize n-body simulation for small system with OpenMP

Tags: c++, optimization, parallel-processing, openmp

I'm trying to parallelize classical molecular dynamics using `OpenMP`.

**The challenge** is that I need to sequentially run many simulations of small systems (<100 atoms) rather then run single large system (e.g. 1 million atoms). For example [here](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/wiki/OpenMP) I run a test for system of **just 13 atoms** running 50 simulations each with ~1000 steps. The results are disappointing:

Results:

- Time 0.15 [s] Without OMP
- Time 0.50 [s] With `omp parallel for reduction(+:E)`
- Time 1.50 [s] With `omp parallel for shared(E)`

=> **Paralelization makes it actually 10x slower!** :-(

**Program structure:**

I parallelize loop over atoms:

```
double evalLJQs_ng4_omp( const Quat4i* neighs, double Rdamp=1.0 ){
    double R2damp = Rdamp*Rdamp;
    double E =0;
    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:E)
    for(int i=0; i<natoms; i++){
       E += evalLJQs_ng4_atom( i, neighs, R2damp );
    }
    return E;
}
```

In the loop I call `evalLJQs_ng4_atom` per each atom, assuming averything is `private`, but it reads some `global` arrays (see comments int the code), for each pair of atoms calls function [getLJQ()](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/blob/f5aacdca77b9fb95b7189ec8daff39a35a9c869c/cpp/common/math/Forces.h#L174) which computes [Lenard-Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lennard-Jones_potential) and Coulomb ineraction energy and force, at the end it write force into global array `fs` (each CPU writes into his own slot `fs[ia]` => no collision).

```
double evalLJQs_ng4_atom( int ia, const Quat4i* neighs, double R2damp ){
    Vec3d        fi   = Vec3dZero;
    Vec3d        pi   = ps    [ia];           // global read   ps    [ia]
    const Vec3d  REQi = REQs  [ia];           // global read   REQs  [ia]
    const Quat4i ngs  = neighs[ia];           // global read   neighs[ia]
    double         E  = 0;
    for(int j=0; j<natoms; j++){
        if(ia==j) continue;                                             // ommit self interaction
        if( (ngs.x==j)||(ngs.y==j)||(ngs.z==j)||(ngs.w==j) ) continue;  // ommit bonded neighborrs
        Vec3d fij   = Vec3dZero;
        const Vec3d pj    = ps  [j];                        // global read   ps  [j]
        const Vec3d REQj  = REQs[j];                        // global read   REQs[j]
        Vec3d REQij; combineREQ( REQj, REQi, REQij );       // pure function (no globals), L-J mixing rule
        E          += getLJQ( pj-pi, REQij, R2damp, fij );  // pure function (no globals), L-J & Coulomb
        fi.add(fij);
    }
    fs[ia].add(fi);           // global write fs[ia]
    return E;
}
```

**NOTES:**

- [this](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/blob/f5aacdca77b9fb95b7189ec8daff39a35a9c869c/cpp/common/molecular/NBFF.h#L130) `#pragma omp parallel` is the only place in larger program where I use OpenMP (or any other) paralelization.
- This paralellized function is just small part within larger [Molecular dynamics loop](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/blob/f5aacdca77b9fb95b7189ec8daff39a35a9c869c/cpp/common/molecular/MolWorld_sp3.h#L679) which call [evalutation of several forcefield components at each step](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/blob/f5aacdca77b9fb95b7189ec8daff39a35a9c869c/cpp/common/molecular/MolWorld_sp3.h#L639). There are other functions, such as [verlet propagator](https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/blob/f5aacdca77b9fb95b7189ec8daff39a35a9c869c/cpp/common/math/DynamicOpt.cpp#L230) which I do not paralelize because it is even less worth it for such small system.
- I understand that the problem is probably the overhead I pay for initilization/uninitialization of parallel context which I do at every simulation step. But I don't know how to do it differently without radical change of program structure (which I don't want to do, because the main reason why I want to use OpenMP is that it is ***non-invasive*** - meaning it use just `#pragma` comments without need to significantly modify the code structure)
- This is related, but I provide more details. [Bad performace of parallelized OpenMP code for particle simulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14061330/bad-performace-of-parallelized-openmp-code-for-particle-simulation)

**EDIT:**

I modified it using `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:E)` rather than `#pragma omp parallel for shared(E)` as recomanded in comments

**EDIT2:**

Can It help paralelize it like this, so I do not have to initialize/deinitialize the parallel context just for one iteration of the simulation?

```
// ToDo: OpenMP paraelization atempt
int run_omp( int niter, double dt, double Fconv, double Flim ){
    int itr=0;
    double F2conv = Fconv*Fconv;
    double R2damp = Rdamp*Rdamp;
    #pragma omp parallel 
    for(int itr=0; itr<niter; itr++){  // Step of molecules dynamics
        double E=0;
        // ------ eval forces due to covalent bonds
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:E)
        for(int ia=0; ia<natoms; ia++){ 
            E += eval_covalent_atom   ( ia );  
            E += eval_nonCovalent_atom( ia ); 
        }
        // ---- assemble forces from back-neighbors due to Newton 3rd law of inertia
        // Synchorization: needed: We need to wait for forces on all atoms being evaluated first
        #pragma omp for
        for(int ia=0; ia<natoms; ia++){
            assemble_atom( ia );
        }
        // ------ move (i.e. update atom positions and velocieits by forces) 
        // Synchronization: We need to wait for all forces being assembled       
        double F2=0;
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:F2)
        for(int ia=0; ia<natoms; ia++){
            F2 += move_atom_GD( ia, dt, Flim );
        }
        if(F2<F2conv)break;
    }
    return itr;
}
```

**EDIT3:**

This is the final working version:

```
int run_omp( int niter, double dt, double Fconv, double Flim ){
    double F2conv = Fconv*Fconv;
    double E=0,F2=0;
    int    itr=0;
    #pragma omp parallel shared(E,F2) private(itr)
    for(itr=0; itr<niter; itr++){
        // This {} should be done just by one of the processors
        #pragma omp single
        {E=0;F2=0;}
        // ------ eval MMFF
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:E)
        for(int ia=0; ia<natoms; ia++){ 
            if(verbosity>3)printf( "atom[%i]@cpu[%i/%i]\n", ia, omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads()  );
            if(ia<nnode)E += eval_atom(ia);
            E += evalLJQs_ng4_PBC_atom( ia ); 
        }
        // ---- assemble (we need to wait when all atoms are evaluated)
        #pragma omp for
        for(int ia=0; ia<natoms; ia++){
            assemble_atom( ia );
        }
        // ------ move
        #pragma omp for reduction(+:F2)
        for(int i=0; i<nvecs; i++){
            F2 += move_atom_MD( i, dt, Flim, 0.99 );
        }
        #pragma omp single 
        if(verbosity>2){printf( "step[%i] E %g |F| %g ncpu[%i] \n", itr, E, F2, omp_get_num_threads() );}
    }
    return itr;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure, how do you measure your time? It is elapsed time, not CPU time, right?

Comment: irrespective of performance, using `shared(E)` is wrong. You need `reduction(+:E)`

Comment: yes, time elapsed. I use python `time.time_ns()` because I run it as library through python interface, I now there will be some overhead due to that, but this still does not explain that time increased. the test it here 
https://github.com/ProkopHapala/FireCore/blob/master/tests/tMMFF/run_propandiol.py

Comment: yes, I tried also version with `omp parallel for reduction(+:E)` with same results. Yet, I'm a bit puzzled when using `omp parallel for reduction(+:E)` because it tells me it cannot do it since `E` is `private`,  in cotnrals `omp parallel for shared(E) private(ia)` seem to me more clear how to use it properly. Nevertheless, the time elapsed is the same in both cases

Comment: Which both cases? You say that the compiler complains if you declare `reduction(+:E)`, so how can you measure the time? Anyway, the way your code is written can only give unpredictable results, `E` must not be shared. I can't see why the compiler would complain with `reduction(+:E)`: could you please post the code with reduction and the exact error message, if any? And the fact the `E` is shared, besides it's wrong, can have some negative impact on performances.

Comment: @PierU I'm trying OpenMP for the first time, and I was not sure how to use `reduction(+:E)` properly. At one point it was working but then I changed something and it stoped. I think the difference was  `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:E)` (work) vs. `#pragma omp for reduction(+:E)` or `#pragma omp parallel reduction(+:E)`  (not working). OK with   `#pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:E)` I get better result `time=0.5s` which is better than `1.5s` with `shared(E)`, but still it is much worse than `0.15s` I get  without OpenMP.

Comment: @PierU - anyway, I don't care about energy `E` so much, I care more about forces which are used to move the atoms. So even if Energy was wrong I did not noticed it, the molecule still relaxed into proper final geometry.

Comment: Is `n` your number of atoms (hence `13`)?

Comment: yes, it is, I will write it more clearly

Comment: So, indeed no wonder why the OpenMP version is slower: the workload in the parallel part is extremely small, and all what you can see are the OpenMP overheads. If your 50 simulations are independant from each other, parallelizing the loop on the simulations would be more efficient, but it looks like this loop is in the Python part of the code... You would need to move it to the Fortran side to be able to parallelize it.

Comment: You have 13 eggs to cook so to do an omelette and you want to do it as fast as possible. You can do it yourself in few minutes, or you can call your friends by phone, wait for them to come, distribute the egg break it mix it and pour the result in the same bowl so to put it in the same frying pan and then finally say to your friend to leave and wait to be alone. Which is faster? Calling your friend is certainly much slower than doing the whole work, so is creating threads, sharing the work, waiting for them and so on. Multithreading is far from being free.

Comment: For small input like here, the key is to take advantage of intra-core parallelism. SIMD and instruction-level parallelisms are the key to get faster performance here. The thing is the loop is written in a way compilers cannot (easily) use SIMD instructions and conditionals prevent the processor to execute the loop efficiently. At this granularity, memory layout and data alignement are also very important. Also note that virtual calls are very expensive in a hot loop : not only they prevent many compiler optimizations, but they are slow to execute by the processor too due to the indirections.

Comment: @JérômeRichard yes, this brings a question: 1) cannot I initialize the threads sooner in the MDloop which run 1000 iterations of this function? The problem is that in the loop there are some non-paralelizable operations (e.g. verlet update of position and velocity)
2) yes, I would like to use SIMD, but what can I do to make it more vectorizable? 3) I don't call any virtual methods there, and the functions `getLJQ()`, `combineREQ()`, `add()` are `inline`

Comment: Parallelizing on the time steps is indeed not possible, as each iteration depends on the previous one. You have to parallelize the 50 simulations.

Comment: @PierU What I meant is that maybe I can open the parallel context for the whole moleculer-dynamics loop, and close it after the molecule is relaxed (after 1000 steps), rather than open and close it every iteration. See **EDIT 2** in my original post. However this needs some synchronization barriers and described (Perhaps I don't know OpenMP enough to do that)

Comment: It should work, but I'm not sure it will help a lot for performances. In practice, OpenMP implementations do not necessarily destroy the threads at the end of each parallel region, they tend to keep them alive even if inactive. Some remarks: 1) there is an implicit barrier (synchro) at the end of each // for loop, no need to add an explicit one; 2) I would add an explicit barrier just before the end of the loop on `itr`; 3) `E` and `F2` should be declared outside of the parallel region, and `shared`

Comment: I would also bracket the initializations of `E` and `F2` in `omp single` directives (or set `omp barrier` ones just after)

Comment: While OpenMP runtimes tends not to create threads over and over, there are many things to initialize and check when a parallel section is done. So having a parallel section with a `single` can indeed help. A `master` close might also be better than a `single` one and cause less issues (since the main thread is guaranteed to be the same).

Comment: Still, communicating between cores has a significant overhead coming directly from the hardware. For example an atomic operation typically takes >20 ns on a mainstream x86 CPU. This is the time to compute several hundreds of floating-point operation (even thousands on high-end recent ones). OpenMP runtimes are not perfect and use several of them (they are not designed to operate at such granularity). Cores can only communicates using the LLC cache on most CPU and its latency is generally >20 ns. On scalable servers this is significantly more because the LLC is larger (and the need to scale).

Comment: On top of that, the scheduler takes several *microseconds* to react when a thread wake up (ie. the time to perform >10_000 flops). Cores can be sleeping so they also need some time to wake up, not to mention it takes time for the frequency to raise (the default frequency is low so to reduce the energy consumption and avoid cores to to be damaged). OpenMP runtimes tends to use an active pooling approach to avoid this. You can tune this with OMP_WAIT_POLICY, but many overheads cannot be really avoided. Each parallel for loop typically takes hundred of ns (often >1 µs on servers).

Comment: Regarding vectorization, you need to use *structure of arrays* rather than array of structure. POO is often bad for vectorization. This is an issue in high-performance codes because recent x86 CPUs can do 2x8=16 FMA operation per cycles while scalar code can only do 2. This is 8x times more. Without changing the layout, the code can hardly vectorized but this is possible if you do that manually (very intrusive). Changing the layout help but there is no guarantee for compilers to generate a good code. Doing this manually often help for performance critical codes. You need to check the asm code.

Comment: Note that regarding the content of your function, the bottleneck might not be the numerical computational speed but cache accesses. You need to do a low-level profiling to check that. Put it shortly, there is no free-lunch. Multithreading has a significant overhead and it is only worth it at heavy grain. If you cannot, then you need to optimize the sequential code using more invasive methods : different layout, SIMD intrinsics, faster instruction using approximations, data prefetching, manual unrolling, etc.